# Upgrade to Angular 4 broke implementation of external JS dependency

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, keycloak

When I upgraded my angular application to angular 4 the following happened:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Keycloak is not defined
        at Function.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/services/auth/auth.service.ts.AuthService.init (auth.service.ts:22)
        at Object.../../../../../src/main.ts (main.ts:9)
        at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 1f6d90b…:54)
        at Object.1 (polyfills.ts:19)
        at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 1f6d90b…:54)
        at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap 1f6d90b…:25)
        at main.bundle.js:1
```

I have removed my **script tags** from the index.html file and instead included them into the angular-cli.json file:

```
  "scripts": [
    "./app/js/keycloak/keycloak.js",
    "./app/js/wavesurfer/wavesurfer.min.js",
    "./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "./app/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js",
    "./app/js/bootstrap/jquery.min.js"
  ]
```

I now get an error on the following code:

```
declare let Keycloak: any;

static init(): Promise<any> {
   let keycloakAuth: any = new Keycloak("app/js/keycloak/keycloak.json");

   // other code here
}
```

**What did I do wrong? The import of the javascript file or the declaration of this object.**

With Angular 2 this worked perfectly.

Let me know if I need to provide more information to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would install [Keycloak JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-js) as well as [its typing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/keycloak-js) through npm:

```
npm install --save keycloak-js @types/keycloak-js
```

Now, you can import it as a polyfill library -- a library that should be loaded before your app is initialized.

In *./src/polyfills.ts*, add

```
import 'keycloak-js' // <- use the keycloak foldername in ./node_modules folder
```

Because we also installed the types, you should even remove the `declare let Keycloak` line because TypeScript will use the `@types/keycloak-js` package to provide strong typing.  Finally, remove the keycloak line from the scripts array of *.angular-cli.json* file.

You should now be able to use Keycloak in your project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it soon!

Comment: I think it worked, the only error I'm getting right now is "zone.js:643 Unhandled Promise rejection: clientId missing ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: clientId missing".

This might be of a wrong versioning of the typings, I will try to resolve it.